# Good resources on recommender systems?

Tags: recommendation-engine

I've taken [Andrew Ng's class on machine learning](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml), and so I feel I have a pretty sound basic understanding of machine learning techniques. I'm aware of the [netflix prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_Prize), and will be reading about the winners.

Is there any good literature available on Amazon's system? Theirs seems to be incredibly effective. Do they keep their methods secret?

Has anyone ever collected a library of important articles on recommender systems? Or a summary/wiki of the important methods used for various systems?

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.tribler.org/trac/raw-attachment/wiki/SimilarityFunction/Amazon-Recommendations.pdf for information about Amazon's recommender system. There are a lot of resources out there about recommender systems.

I suppose you should start with the following 3

User based collaborative filtering
Item based collaborative filtering
Matrix Factorization collaborative filtering

Comment: Any idea where I can learn about those 3 collaborative filtering techniques? The simpler the explanation the better. It's pretty annoying how people who write academic papers always assume their audience knows exactly as much as they did about their topic right before developing whatever it is they're writing about...

Comment: I'd suggest picking up a copy of programming collective intelligence from O'Reilly. They will give you the basics of user and item based recommendation. After that if you want to learn about MF you need to become familiar with machine learning, optimization, regularization, regression and so on. It's more advanced and probably less intuitive than user and item based.

Comment: http://www.jscires.org/sites/default/files/10.5530jscires.5.1.10.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [monograph](http://arek-paterek.com/book) about the Netflix Prize and recommender systems (it is not free though). It contains a brief introduction to predictive modeling